# bettercap v2 installation

Tags: software-installation, golang

I'm trying to install bettercap by following this page https://www.bettercap.org/installation/#linux-deploy-method-debian-based-like-ubuntu

but it is not installing, what to do?

Comment: Providing OS & release details are a start.  What command did you get up to, and what output did you get where you got stuck?

Comment: Assume `go` in your PATH : `$ cd bettercap/ && make build && sudo make install` : You can now use the command `$ bettercap --help`